# Change Default Handling for Exception class in Python

Tags: python, exception

I have a simple question with a likely more complicated answer.

I wrote a custom Exception class in Python:

```
class MyError(Exception):
  def __init__(self, message, other_info):
    Exception.__init__(self, message)
    self.other_info = other_info
```

What I would like to do is alter the default handling of this exception to include the information in `other_info`, but I want to keep it out of the main Exception message for organization's sake.

I have seen a post on how to override `sys.excepthook` entirely, but I don't want to change how it works -- I just want to change the way `MyError` is handled. Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps you are just looking to override the `__str__` method of the exception? Other than the type, which you can match in an `except` clause, the exception handling system doesn't really deal with the internal details of an exception object. Those details are for use by the particular handling code when you catch a specific exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to understand what you meant by *alter the default handling* and guessed that you want the exception message to display `self.other_info` instead of `self.message`. If that is the case, modify the class to add the `__str__` function:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg, other_info):
        Exception.__init__(self, msg)
        self.other_info = other_info
    def __str__(self):
        return '<MyError: {}>'.format(self.other_info)
        # Or, simply:
        # return self.other_info
```

Comment: Good call on `__str__` -- I didn't even think to use that. While this isn't exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, it will work for my needs. Thanks.